# Bifurcation diagrams,value and classification

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, bifurcation

I got the following dynamical system in 1-d, $$\dot x = (x+\mu)(\mu+2x-x^2)$$

Im asked to find dependence of the the stationary points of the system and its stability with respect the $\mu$ parameter. Then draw the bifurcation diagram and find at which $\mu$ the bifurcation occurs.

Before showing my attempt of solution I have to say sorry, but Im really lost and I havent found any reference to study this properly. Here we go,

**Attempt of partial solution**

For the stationary(fixed points), we have that $x=-\mu$ or $x=1\pm 1\sqrt{1+\mu}$. So, now we have to analyze stability for the cases $\mu >-1$ and $\mu <-1$. We will check the sign of $\frac{d((x+\mu)(\mu+2x-x^2))}{dx} = 3\mu + 4x - 2 \mu x - 3 x^2$.

Case 0: $\mu = -1$ theres only one stationary point which is x=1.

Case 1: $\mu >-1$,

1.1)For $x=-\mu$, $\frac{d((x+\mu)(\mu+2x-x^2))}{dx} = 3\mu-4\mu+2\mu^{2}-3\mu^{2}<0$. So, $x=-\mu$ is stable.

1.2)For $x= 1+1\sqrt{1+\mu}$, $\frac{d((x+\mu)(\mu+2x-x^2))}{dx}=-2 (\mu + 1)( \sqrt{\mu+ 1} + 1)<0$

1.3) For $x = 1-1\sqrt{1+\mu}$, $\frac{d((x+\mu)(\mu+2x-x^2))}{dx}=2 (1 + \mu) (-1 + \sqrt{1 + \mu})>0$ which implies it is unstable.

Case 2:$\mu <-1$

The way to work it is analogous to what we did in C.1.

Now, I have no idea how to draw the bifurcation diagram. Its only one diagram or its 1 for each case?, what exactly means that 'a bifurcation occurs' and how do I classify these points into pitchfork, saddle node and transcritical?

Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it. <3

Comment: Could you check for small details like the bifurcation point not being $1$ or the solution of the quadratic equation being slightly wrong? Also, $1$ is not $0$ in case 0.

Comment: Sorry, I didint right it correctly :c, now its edited. Thanks for taking the time to note it :)

Comment: The main point to observe for $\mu<-1$ is that there are no real roots of the quadratic term, it is always negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*bifucation graph*

[image]

Note that the behavior of the vector field at large values of $x$ never changes in quality, it always points towards the origin. As the roots, except at the triple and crossing point, are simple, you always have that the middle root is unstable and the outer roots are stable.

Let's look again at the $x$-derivative of the right side. By the product rule, it is
$$
1(μ+2x-x^2)+(x+μ)(2-2x)=μ+2x-x^2+2(μ+(1-μ)x-x^2)=3μ+2(2-μ)x-3x^2
$$

- For $x=-\mu$, this reduces to $μ-2μ-μ^2=-μ(1+μ)$, so the stability changes at the triple point $μ=-1$ and again at the crossing point $μ=0$.
- For $μ>-1$ and the quadratic roots, the derivative expression reduces to
  $$
  1(μ+2x-x^2)+2(x+μ)(1-x)=2(μ+(1-μ)x-x^2)=-2(1+μ)x.
  $$
  and thus for $x=1\pm\sqrt{1+μ}$ this is negative as long as both roots stay positive and changes to positive as the lower root becomes negative for $μ>0$.

Comment: Thanks so much sir, but since we have the bifurcation diagram, is it possible to find the type of the bifurcation just by looking the diagram? I mean, is it possible to know if it is transcritical, saddle-node or pitchfork just by looking the diagram? Cause Im not sure how to do it :o

Comment: You will have to ensure that the roots are in the main simple. And then yes, what looks like a pitchfork is also a pitchfork etc. The basic bifurcation types (in generic position, that is, stable under small perturbation) are defined to have a very typical (local) picture.

Comment: Thanks again sir, and just one last thing, here the bifurcation point would be $\mu=-1$?

Comment: Yes, just as you also found out. $μ=0$ is also a critical point, a trans-critical point in this case. Under perturbation of the right side, the pitchfork can decompose into a saddle point followed by a trans-critical point.